# Hibernate transaction problem

Tags: java, hibernate

When I execute some queries inside Hibernate transaction -> the data successfully updated in my mysql, but in my application there are still old values. When i restart - it`s Ok. If i set autocommit mode - works fine, but i have to use transaction ;-). Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are the old values? in the hibernate model objects?

Comment: How are you doing the update?  Are you using 2nd level caching? When you say you use autocommit mode it updates the model but not when using transactions?

Comment: Yes. I have two methods - in first i update table. All queries executes without error, and transaction.commit() is executing. When i select in mysql query browser - its OK(new values). But when i load my UI with second method(which only loads db rows), there are old values. If I exit program and restart - new values are there(in my UI) ???

Comment: Sorry, but i dont know what means "2nd level caching"

Comment: ok, don't worry about the caching then haha.  can you show where your model/container that holds the data for your UI is being manipulated/updated?

Answer (score 1):

Manipulating the database directly with UPDATE doesn't affect the objects cached in the session. You should clear the session (Session.clear()). Something like:

```
session.flush()
session.clear()
query.executeUpdate()
```

Or even better, you can avoid the problem by not using update queries and manipulating the object state in memory:

```
myobj.setName(newValue)
session.saveOrUpdate(myobj)
```

Comment: yeah I have a feeling that this not being done, but not sure without more info :)

Comment: Yeah, I suspect there are some fundamental misunderstandings. 2nd level caching may be enabled without him knowing. The best advice I can give Nikolay at this point is to read the Hibernate manual from beginning to end :-)

Comment: I read all day about hibernate session/transactions... and mistery was solved ;-) The problem was not in update method, but in those which returns result. it simply construct criteria, and returns "uniqueResult" but it wasn`t inside transaction. Why i need transaction here? It`s only one select query? Thanks everyone for helping!

Answer (score 0):

In `hibernate` either you are using `JPA API` or Hibernate's native API any query that you run using below interface

1. **Criteria (Hibernate Native API)**
2. **Query (Hibernate Native API)**
3. **EntityManager createQuery() (JPA)**

The queries dont interact with the second level or first level cache . They directly hit the database .If your query is updating the entities currently in the persistence context , those entities will not reflect the changes.This is the default behavior.

In order to update your context to show the latest state of entity use the refresh() in Session or in EntityManager to reflect the latest entity state in persistence context.
Read the docs below for more info

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#refresh%28java.lang.Object%29

Otherwise as a convention always run your `DML` before loading any data in the persistence context.

Hope this helps :D